# Weird IE7 js issue in Drupal

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events, internet-explorer-7, drupal-6

In IE 7 when I click on any Javascript link for example

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleGroup(); return false;" id="slick-toggle">View Classrooms</a>
```

the page will refresh. This is occurring in a Drupal project I inherited. This problem doesn't happen in IE7 when I run the same script outside of Drupal.

Even in the Drupal admin `onclick` events cause the page to reload.

You can see the behavior here: http://www.goswerve.com/drupalsite/NDT_classroom_locations.php?locZip=98021
(Click on the "View Classrooms 11 - 21" link.)

Interestingly if you add a number at the end of the url above then that same link works as intended.

Neither my boss or I can figure this out. I'm not even sure it's Drupal issue. Any guidance on how to trouble-shoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.
My js skills are mediocre so keep that in mind. If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line inside my body tag.

onresize="window.location=window.location;"

Took it out and every thing works now!